How to store data globally in custom service for each api request in a .NET 8 rest api project (without using HttpContext)
I want to store the value data in service globally and use in different layers doing dependency injection in ASP.NET Core 8 Web API project. I am using clean architecture.
public interface ISharedDataService
{
    void SetTrustedPartnerDetails(object trustedPartnerDetails);
    object GetTrustedPartnerDetails();
}

public class SharedDataService : ISharedDataService
{
    private object _trustedPartnerDetails;

    public void SetTrustedPartnerDetails(object trustedPartnerDetails)
    {
        _trustedPartnerDetails = trustedPartnerDetails;
    }

    public object GetTrustedPartnerDetails()
    {
        return _trustedPartnerDetails;
    }
}

// In Program.cs or Startup.cs
services.AddScoped<ISharedDataService, SharedDataService>();

I have set the data in service in middleware and I want to get the data in API controller without using HttpContext.
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ISharedDataService _sharedDataService;

    public ExampleController(ISharedDataService sharedDataService)
    {
        _sharedDataService = sharedDataService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetTrustedPartnerDetails()
    {
        var trustedPartnerDetails = _sharedDataService.GetTrustedPartnerDetails();

        if (trustedPartnerDetails == null)
        {
            return NotFound("Trusted Partner details not found.");
        }

        return Ok(trustedPartnerDetails);
    }
}

But in the API controller,  _sharedDataService.GetTrustedPartnerDetails() always returns NULL.
How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Hard to tell exactly what you are doing here, but accessing the data in different layers does raise some red flags to me. sounds to me like you need a cache though, perhaps look into IMemoryCache, though I would wrap that with your own class to abstract it away.

Where are you calling SetTrustedPartnerDetails at?

@DavidG Thanks you for the reply. So, is storing the data in httpcontext and passing it different layers is the only safest way ? As IMemoryCache is singleton service by default and i cant use it because then I have to implementing a custom caching mechanism scoped to the request.

@GHDevOps In middleware

You need to confirm if the "_trustedPartnerDetails = trustedPartnerDetails;" is not null. Then check the lifetime to makesure this service is not disposed. I think you need singleton lifetime for this.
